# Accessing an ancestor node on XMLType

Tags: xml, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a PLSQL procedure which takes an XMLType argument. 
I have a requirement to change the procedure to operate differently based on the **parent** node of the argument.

If I was in C# I could just access XmlNode.ParentNode. Is there a similar concept in PLSQL?

So far the best option I have is to pass the root node and an xpath into the procedure and select the nodes I need within the procedure. This starts to get unwieldy when the behavior within the function should be governed by an arbitrary ancestor.

Comment: Can you not just change the procedure to accept two parameters a string with the ancestor and then the xmltype, and handle it in the caller which has the whole xml anyway?

Comment: @ShaunPeterson ancestor string is the technique I'm using, but it feels like there should be some sort of XML DOM to use (perhaps that's just my dot net prejudices). I don't want to implement in the caller as, in this case, that would mean implementing the same functionality in many places